# mysql insert varbinary column changed to numbers

Tags: string, mediawiki, mysql, varbinary

I am moving mediawiki from my localhost (windows) to linux server. When i tried to import my mediawiki dump file into server all the string columns converted to number.

For ex:
mediawiki `user` table is having `user_name` columnn which is having varbinary datatype. After import in linux server I could see all the `user_name` column changed numbers. (username :Wiki changed to 57696b69)

Localhost mysql version is 5.1.37
Linux server mysql version is 5.6.25

Is there anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: When you where dumping, did you specify any options?

Comment: No i didnt specify anything! even in command line if i execute one insert row also i am getting the same issue.